# Is using a Subquery is the best way to use GROUP_CONCAT() on none-related table?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

In this Query

```
SELECT username, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(color) FROM colors) FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

Is this the best and only way to get all the `colors` from the table `colors`? I can't figure out a way to `INDEX` the `colors` table to make it fast, So I have my concerns.

```
users: id(int(11), Primary), username(varchar(12), Unique)
colors: id(int(11), Primary), color(varchar(12), Unique)
```

Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/064c34/2/0

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also be helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated to add the sample and tag.

Comment: Get rid of `id` in `colors`; promote `color` to be the PK.  (This won't address the Question.)

Comment: @RickJames never used a PK before, Will check how they work and follow your advice now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically the only option.

You could move the subquery to the `FROM` clause.  That would guarantee that it gets executed only once.  However, you are selecting only one row, so it should be executed only once.

Why do you think that the query is slow?  Given that the default length for the `group_concat()` is 1,024 characters, you cannot be aggregating that many values together.

Well, there *is* another option:

```
select u.*, c.colors
from users u cross join
     (select @c as colors
      from (select @c := concat(@c, ',', c.color)
            from colors c cross join
                 (select @c := '') params
           ) c
      limit 1
     ) c
where u.id = 1;
```

I would be surprised if this provided better performance.

Comment: I expected the `EXPLAIN` to use the `Unique Key` or something, But was surprised it didn't, So I had concerns that I'm doing it wrong using `Subquery`. I would like to understand How could it be moved to `FROM` if possible.